# Conexão de programa em Delphi compilado para win64 com Firebird 64

Tags: delphi

Tenho um aplicativo escrito em `Delphi` (`XE3`) usando `IBX`,  que compila em 32 e 64 bits. Rodando no windows 10 64 bits o programa em 32 conecta normalmente, mas o de 64 tem a conexão rejeitada pelo `firebird`.

> "CONNECTION REJECTED BY REMOTE INTERFACE"

Instalei as `dlls` do Firebird como `gds32` no `system32` e a versão de 32 bits no `syswow64`.  Na verdade a `dll` gerada pela instalação do `firebird` que fica na pasta `WOW64` da instalação do `Firebird 2.5.8`.

Desbloqueei a porta 3050 no Firewall e os 2 executáveis também.

Estou sem saber o que fazer.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz.

Grato.

*P.S. O windows 10 pro está na ultima versão 1803.*

Comment: Coloca a solução como resposta e depois marque a resposta como sendo a solução do seu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Felizmente descobri que a dll usada pelo Delphi no componente TIbDataBase muda para IbClient64.dll ao invés de GDS32.dll, quando compilado para win64,. renomeei a dll do Firebird FbClient.dll para IbClient64.dll e o problema ficou resolvido.